# Getting flat error curves while training when deep learning with BP neural nets

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, prediction, backpropagation

I am always getting flat curves for error plots while deep learning with conventional BP neural networks. I am using Keras sequential model with Adam optimiser. The NN giving overall 80% accuracy both for training and testing. Can anyone explain why the error curves are flat (see attached figure)? Also is there any way to improve my results?

```
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential()
  model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=len(normed_train_data.keys())]))
  model.add(layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(1,)))
  model.add(layers.Dense(4))
  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam',metrics=['mae', 'mse','accuracy'])
  return model

def plot_history(history):
   hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
   hist['epoch'] = history.epoch
   plt.figure()
   plt.xlabel('Epoch')
   plt.ylabel('Mean Abs Error [per]')
   plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['mean_absolute_error'],label='Train Error')
   plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['val_mean_absolute_error'],label = 'Val Error')
   plt.legend()
   plt.ylim([0,200])
   plt.show()
```

And in the main function,

```
model = build_model()
model.summary()
history = model.fit(normed_train_data, train_labels,epochs=EPOCHS,validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0,callbacks=[PrintDot()])
hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
hist['epoch'] = history.epoch
plot_history(history)
```

error plots :

[image]

[Error plot with reduced learning rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FQnC.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to assess that without having more information about your data, can you share a sample? But I'd hazard a guess that your model overfits very quickly. Things that you can try:

- model simplification -- try removing one layer, or using less units for starters
- different optimizer, try sgd with different learning rates
- different metrics (try removing one by one)

Comment: sample input vector: [9349 8699 8836 13316 12771 0.2022 -0.2097 -0.0209]---features,   sample output vector: [5.56 13.89 0.00 80.56]---these are probability values. I am doing training with 4,52,995 samples.

Comment: I am normalising the input features before feeding to the network

Comment: I have already tried with different number of layers and optimizers, but getting almost same result.

Comment: If its over fitting, how I get the same accuracy for the test data (sometimes little more)?? I am using 113249 samples for testing.

Comment: Also I don't think, changing the metric will improve the results, because, it is documented as: "A metric function is similar to a loss function, except that the results from evaluating a metric are not used when training the model."